# How to show Xml data in the winform in the XML fashion?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xml-serialization

My winform application communicates with the web service. For some requirement, I need to present the web service response in the XML format in the winform application.

I can serialize the response type (class) instance to XML string. But when i show that string in the rich text box, it's obviously displayed as continuous string; not as the XML as shown below.

```
<UserServiceAccesses>
- <UserServiceAccess>
-   <Service>
       <ID>0</ID> 
       <LocalID>Loggerr</LocalID> 
       <SystemID>-1</SystemID> 
       <ServiceType>U</ServiceType> 
       <Name>MyLogger</Name> 
       </Service>
    <ClientPermissions /> 
  </UserServiceAccess>
- <UserServiceAccess>
-     <Service>
         <ID>0</ID> 
         <LocalID>Logger2</LocalID> 
         <SystemID>-1</SystemID> 
         <ServiceType>U</ServiceType> 
         <Name>MyLogger2</Name> 
     </Service>
     <ClientPermissions /> 
  </UserServiceAccess>
<UserServiceAccesses>
```

Here, `UserServiceAccesses` is the class which has property of type `UserServiceAccess`. Then `UserServiceAccess` has a properties of type `Service`, `ClientPermissions`

How can I do it? It can be in any form (tree, table, text etc.) but it should be readable as XML. Since there are many web methods we call from application, everytime XML structure would be different and so we cannot have definite schema.

Comment: is the posted code is helpful ??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make use of **TreeView control**

Here is working code to display xml on **treeview** :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

public class XmlTreeDisplay : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.TreeView treeXml = new TreeView();

    public XmlTreeDisplay()
    {
        treeXml.Nodes.Clear();
        this.Controls.Add(treeXml);
        // Load the XML Document
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            doc.LoadXml("<books><A property='a'><B>text</B><C>textg</C><D>99999</D></A></books>");
            //doc.Load("");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            return;
        }

        ConvertXmlNodeToTreeNode(doc, treeXml.Nodes);
        treeXml.Nodes[0].ExpandAll();
    }

    private void ConvertXmlNodeToTreeNode(XmlNode xmlNode,
      TreeNodeCollection treeNodes)
    {

        TreeNode newTreeNode = treeNodes.Add(xmlNode.Name);

        switch (xmlNode.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                newTreeNode.Text = "<?" + xmlNode.Name + " " +
                  xmlNode.Value + "?>";
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                newTreeNode.Text = "<" + xmlNode.Name + ">";
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                newTreeNode.Text = "ATTRIBUTE: " + xmlNode.Name;
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                newTreeNode.Text = xmlNode.Value;
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                newTreeNode.Text = "<!--" + xmlNode.Value + "-->";
                break;
        }

        if (xmlNode.Attributes != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in xmlNode.Attributes)
            {
                ConvertXmlNodeToTreeNode(attribute, newTreeNode.Nodes);
            }
        }
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            ConvertXmlNodeToTreeNode(childNode, newTreeNode.Nodes);
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new XmlTreeDisplay());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. This is exactly what I was looking for. I also found this MS support article that provides some sample code to do the same thing: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317597

Answer (score 23):

Try to apply indent to the xmlText, like:

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);
myRichTextBox.Text = xDocument.ToString();//ToString will format xml string with indent
//as XDocument class overrides ToString and return xml with indent
```

Answer (score 10):

One easy way is to embed an Internet Explorer ActiveX control in the form and load the XML into it.  It would be displayed with IE's default stylesheet for XML.
Sort of like using an iframe element in a web page.

Comment: To add to this answer, this what I came up with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157545/how-can-i-display-xml-with-webbrowser-control/42080286#42080286